# Excel - avoiding indirect

Tags: excel

I have the following three columns A,B,C

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ExcelRangedName | Default Value |                     Formula Check                      |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Name1           |               | =IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(INDIRECT(A2))),"Yes","No") |
| Name2           | FALSE         | …                                                      |
| Name3           | TRUE          | …                                                      |
| Name4           | 0             | …                                                      |
| Name5           | Alpha         | …                                                      |
| Name6           |               | …                                                      |
| Name7           |               | …                                                      |
| Name8           |               | …                                                      |
| …               | …             | …                                                      |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

The column "ExcelRangedName" has text which refers to a range name in other worksheets. I want to replace the formula to remove the indirect completely as it is slowing down my worksheet. I remember being able to do this using paste values trick but I completely forgot how. I want my formula to look (for the first row):

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(Name1)),"Yes","No")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: with out vba to parse the formula directly I do not think it possible to do what you want.

Comment: How would you do with VBA?

Comment: You would loop the formula column, using instr and mid to find the INDIRECT and then find the reference in that part and replace the whole INDIRECT with the value in that reference.